How can I model curved ramp corner pieces for different angles?
I want to create separate edge pieces with different angles that align with those "ramps." It doesn't really matter how "big" the edge piece is, but I am looking for an easy way to create multiple corner pieces with different degrees.


Can you possibly show some images of what you're trying to accomplish? I don't fully understand your question with the images you have alone.

Sorry it's hard to express what i want in english (but it should not be).  I added another picture maybe it helps. I want to create  a piece that connects the two ramps to create a curved ramp.

Duplicate the extremity of each piece, join them in one piece and bridge them?

You can start with a flat curved mesh and make sure both meshes you want to connect are in one object. Select the two edge loops you want to connect and then press Ctrl+E > Bridge Edge Loops. In the Adjust Last Operation panel, increase the Number of Cuts parameter to the desired level.

And then add a Solidify Modifier

You can also start with one mesh and then use the Spin Tool. Set the Transform Pivot Point to 3D Cursor. Select the bottom vertex and press Shift+S > Cursor to Selected. Select the edge loop, then click the Spin Tool and set the axis to the Z-axis. Click and drag the plus icon to spin by the desired amount, such as 90 degrees, for example. You can adjust other parameters as well within the Adjust Last Operation panel such as the Steps. Then add a Solidify Modifier when done modeling.

You can also use beveling with Ctrl+B and press C to clamp the bevel to get some nice quad topology on 90 degree turns. Don't forget to do M > Merge By Distance so you eliminate overlapping vertices.

Then with Solidify Modifier:


If you take the edge of the main "straight ramp", then add these modifiers you can get a corner like this.



Or you can use a mirror modifier with a mirror object rotated like this to get a "corner" effect, rather than a bowl.


Hello thanks for the answer. The first one is exactly what i want to do but i still cant get it to work. Sorry im new to blender i cant get it at work at all can you describe a bit more what i should do? Should i seperate the edge? Should the edge be subdivided? Should i add the modifiers only to the edge? Sorry for the dumb quewstions and thanks for the help

Yes, copy the far edge of your main ramp into a new object. Select the edges, Shift+D in edit mode, then P > Selection. Then add the screw modifier like in my post.
